# Is this valid application of the rational root theorem?

Tags: polynomials, roots

I suspect this reasoning is not valid, but wanted to check it - let's say I'm trying to find positive integer roots for some $x$ with an unknown integer $k$. I can arrange it as follows:

$-x^3 + 3(x+k) + 3(x+k)^2 + 1 = 0$

If this were allowed, I would then say the only possible integer root is $+1$, and solving this, I arrive at two possible values for $k$ of $k = -1$ and $k=-2$. Both of which work, but are these the only solutions, and is this arrangement valid? Because equally, I think the constant term is really $3k^2 + 3k + 1$, in which case my approach seems misguided. It feels like this is wrong, but open to hearing more about how others might approach it.

Comment: This is hard to follow.  If $P(x)$ is your polynomial then the constant term is $P(0)$, doesn't matter where in the expression you put your constant.  If I wrote $x^2+1-1$ would you say the constant term was $-1$ because that's what I wrote last?

Comment: I'm probably explaining this badly: the full polynomial is:

$-x^3 + 3x^2 + 3x + 6xk + 3k^2 + 3k + 1$ 

where $k$ is some constant. In this case, I think the "real" P(0) term is $3k^2 + 3k +1$ and then my approach would be wrong. But that it finds me some viable values makes me curious...

Comment: Every divisor of $1$ is also a divisor of $3k^2+3k+1$.  In any case, the constant term of your expression is definitely $3k^2+3k+1$.